# I cannot import gdal in Python 3.9.4, even if I've installed it successfully

Tags: python, gdal

I have an issue in importing gdal in Python 3.9.4.

I installed "gdal-302-1928-x64-core.msi" and "GDAL-3.2.1.win-amd64-py3.6.msi" taken from https://gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1928-x64-gdal-3-2-1-mapserver-7-6-2.zip

I also installed "GDAL-3.2.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl" taken from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

When I tried to import it, it looks like this:
[click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNmNQ.jpg)

It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File stdin, line 1, in module. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'
```

For setting environmental & system variables, I've managed it well, but still not helping me.
Probably I should install "GDAL-3.2.2.win-amd64-py3.9.msi" but I don't find it in https://gisinternals.com/

Could someone help me? Thank you.

Regards,
Arfah

Comment: Use [`from osgeo import gdal`](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.2.1/gdal/MIGRATION_GUIDE.TXT#L1-L7)

Answer (score 3):

Always download packages suitable to the Python version you are using. Yes correctly:"GDAL-3.2.2.win-amd64-py3.9.msi" should be installed,and by doing so automatically the osgeo along with teh egg-info package will be installed in $PYTHONPATH/Lib/site-packages/.

To correct the error, you should use:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

Comment: Does this mean you need to install gdal separately for every python version you use? Anyone know if there's a way to get the Ubuntu apt package manager to install gdal for other versions of Python? (Right now I tried Focal and I think Impish, and both installed gdal for Python 3.8 even though Impish has 3.9 as the default.)

Comment: Hi Adair, I think if gdal is with python 3.8.  any version beyond it will be backward compatible.